# Using blowfish encryption with Android?

Tags: android, cryptography, blowfish, encryption

I'm trying to use a blowfish cipher inside an Android application.
It appears that the Android platform supports blowfish (it appears to be in the source code), but when I try to get a cipher using:

```
Cipher.getInstance("blowfish"); 

I get a "java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a quick Google search, try a capital `B` in `"Blowfish"`, and see if that helps.

Comment: I checked that too, sadly, no joy

Comment: Ah, it looks like it was commented out as a provider. See http://bit.ly/dyUAOa -- all occurrences of Blowfish are commented out as "android-removed". I'm not quite sure why, as a cursory glance suggests the source is actually there, so it's not a space issue...

Comment: Do you know of a good stand-alone blowfish cipher out there?  I've tried pulling in bouncy castle, but my dex step chokes on all the extra code.

Comment: Yeah, your Bouncy Castle will conflict with the built-in Bouncy Castle -- too much bouncing will screw up the accelerometer. :-) The GNU Crypto project has a Blowfish implementation http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-crypto/ -- it's GPL with the library exception, so I think you're OK to include it in your app without having to go GPL for the whole thing.

Comment: Marked as the answer because your comment was insightful, not because "Blowfish" worked ;-)